# How to copy a sentence into a char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to copy a sentence into a `char` array. I have tried using `scanf("%[^\n])` and `scanf("%[^\n]\n` within an `if` statement but it doesn't work. Can someone please help me figure it out? I am using C language. It works with the first code but not the second.

**File #1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   char c[10];
   printf ("Enter text.\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]", c);
   printf ("text:%s", c);
   return 0;
 }
```

**File #2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char command[10];
  char c[10];

  printf("cmd> ");
  scanf( "%s", command);

  if (strcmp(command, "new")==0)

  { 

     printf ("Enter text:\n");
     scanf("%[^\n]", c);
     printf ("text:%s\n", c);

  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PLease be more specific.  What does, "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Is `%[^\n]` standard?

Comment: The line `scanf("%s", command)` is leaving the newline in the input buffer, and the second `scanf` is just reading the empty string before it.

Comment: 2. use `scanf(" %9[^\n]", c);`

Comment: @ikh: Yes. Matches everything but `'\n'`.

Comment: @Barmar: Don't you mean: Cannot match newline? (It should return 0 matches)

Comment: I mean that the first scanf reads everything up to first whitespace, which is probably a newline, and leaves the newline in the buffer. The second scanf then reads everything up to the newline, which means it reads nothing because the newline is at the beginning of the input buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space before `%[^\n]` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char command[10];
  char c[10];

  printf("cmd> ");
  scanf( "%s", command);

  if (strcmp(command, "new")==0)
  { 
     printf ("Enter text:");
     scanf(" %[^\n]", c); // note the space
     printf ("text:%s", c);

  }
    return 0;
}
```

It should work now. The space makes it consume any whitespace of the previous inputs.

Here's my output when I tested it without the space:

```
cmd> new
Enter text:text:@
------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
```

And with the space:

```
cmd> new
Enter text:test
text:test
------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks guys. It works like a charm. The issue was indeed the space.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page of scanf function, the usual skip of leading white space is suppressed if you use the [ character in the format string. So in the first case, it accepts all the characters until it meets the \n character; In the second case, after the first call of scanf function, the \n character (you press the Enter key in the first call) is still in the input buffer, so if you uses the format string `"%[^\n]"` in the scanf function, it reads an empty string into the buffer (As already mentioned, it skips the white space in this format case). So you can use the format string `" %[^\n]"` to force the scanf function to skip the white space.